# using rvest to read table from web

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new to R and web scraping. I'm trying to read a table from the World Bank website into R.

Here is the url link for one of the projects as an example (my goal is to read the left table under "Basic Information"): http://projects.worldbank.org/P156880/?lang=en&tab=details

I'm using Chrome's Dedvtools to identify the selector nodes that i need for that particular table.

Here is my code:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://projects.worldbank.org/P156880/?lang=en&tab=details"
details <- url %>% 
        read_html() %>% 
        html_nodes(css = '#projectDetails > div:nth-child(2) > div.column-left > table') %>%
        html_table()
```

Unfortunately, I get an empty list:

```
> details
list()
```

Any help on  how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The table are rendered with JavaScript, you need to use PhantomJS or something similar to actually run underline JavaScript and get the proper rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This site uses XML http requests which you can get using `httr`.  Open Chrome developer tools and go to the Network tab and then load your url above.  You will notice four other urls are requested when loading the page, so click on `projectdetails?` and you should see the html table in the Preview tab.  Next, right click on `projectdetails?` and Copy as cURL to a text editor and paste the URL, Referer, and X-Requested-With into the httr GET function below.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

res <- GET(
  url = "http://projects.worldbank.org/p2e/projectdetails?projId=P156880&lang=en",
  add_headers(Referer = "http://projects.worldbank.org/P156880/?lang=en&tab=details", 
   `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest")
)  
content(res) %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table( header=TRUE)
                Project ID                     P156880
  1                 Status                      Active
  2          Approval Date           December 14, 2017
  3           Closing Date           December 15, 2023
  4                Country                    Colombia
  5                 Region Latin America and Caribbean
  6 Environmental Category                           B
```

Or write a function to get any project ID

```
 get_project <-function(id){
   res <- GET(
     url = "http://projects.worldbank.org",
    path = paste0("p2e/projectdetails?projId=", id, "&lang=en"),
    add_headers(
      Referer = paste0("http://projects.worldbank.org/", id, "/?lang=en&tab=details"), 
      `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest")
  ) 
  content(res) %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table(header=TRUE)
}
get_project("P156880")
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for your code. I tried copying the cURL after right-clicking on the `projectdetails?`  but it gave me a very long URL (so long it  got compressed in the R console). Would help to get some clarification on how the URL is obtained. Thank you!

Comment: I added a few more details to the answer.  Just copy the cURL to a text editor and then paste a few of the fields into the GET options.  I don't think you need headers like Cookie, User-Agent or others.

Comment: Actually, you can just read the URL that the page loads using `read_html( "http://projects.worldbank.org/p2e/projectdetails?projId=P156880&lang=en") %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table( header=TRUE)`